# Intallshield setup for c# desktop application in microsoft visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, installshield

I am working with c# winform application and I am using access database as back-end. I created the setup file for my application in visual studio by installshield(Added the application plus database file will creating the database) but when I installed the software in other systems then it get installed.But problem is when I performing task related to my data base it giving "Path does not find of c:...." the path which I seen in this error message is the same path which I given in coding for connection. But I want a setup which able to use in any pc and the software automatically get the path of database in any system so please tell is this possible by any other software or install shield can do my work?Please help!!

```
namespace AryanClinic1
{
    public partial class SearchPg : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection my_con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Sonu\Downloads\GiveProduct\DoneHome\AryanClinic1\AryanClinic1\ClinicMainDatabase.accdb");
       OleDbCommand o_cmd = my_con.CreateCommand();
                o_cmd.CommandText = @"
                                    INSERT INTO RegisterTable1 (UserName,[Password],[RetypePassword],SecurityQuestion,Answer) 
                                    VALUES                       (@User_Name,@Pass,@RetypePass,@Security_Question,@Answer)";

                o_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", txtUserName.Text);
                o_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", txtPassword.Text);
                o_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RetypePass", txtRetypePassword.Text);
                o_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Security_Question", txtSecurityQuestion.Text);
                o_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Answer", txtAnswer.Text);

                int i = o_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }}}
```

This is some of my code of forms. My setup is depend on this project file of my application.If I moved this project file then also it showing the error.

I Followed this steps in installshield-
Created the installshield project-->At Application information given company name plus version clicked next-->installation requirement I does not select anything(keep radio no for 2)-->Application form Added two file(1st project application file 2nd  access database file)-->Application shortcut create shortcut at menu and desktop checked-->Application registry made all yes then built solution got exe setup.

I want a setup which able to use in any pc and the software automatically get the path of database in any system so please tell is this possible by any other software or install shield can do my work?Please help!!

[Error Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbYeP.jpg)

Comment: You need to include more information. What database are you using? What does your connection string look like?

Comment: Yes sir you are right I updated my question.

Comment: Don't give hardcoded database path. The Accessfile you added in installshield wizard will present in installed application program files.

Comment: In your program give the path to that database which is present in program files. Or Each windows application has its own APPDATA folder. Try to copy your access db into APPDATA and use.     Dont hardcode path names.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion sir I am going to follow your suggestion.